# How to set up identical lists?

Tags: python

The output shown will say it's not identical, but how can I automatically do the lists with `random.randint(1,6)`, so it can keep guessing whether if both are identical or not instead of doing it manually?

```
import random 

test_list1 = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5] 
test_list2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 

print ("The first list is : " + str(test_list1)) 
print ("The second list is : " + str(test_list2)) 

test_list1.sort) 
test_list2.sort() 

if test_list1 == test_list2: 
    print ("The lists are identical") 
else : 
    print ("The lists are not identical")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `random.randint(1,6)` and a list comprehension to generate lists of 5 random numbers between 1 and 6 using:

```
test_list1 = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(5)]                           
test_list2 = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(5)]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what I asked for! I'll accept your answer as soon it allows me.

Comment: `random.sample` would do something completely different - it would sample **without replacement** from the given population, so you couldn't get the same number twice in a sample. Also, `random.randint(1, 6)` includes `6`, while `range(1, 6)` doesn't.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks for pointing that out - removed.